# Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/ [FileProvider]

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

i'm new in android and now i've stucked in generate the content Uri.
i have showed all files in directory from a listView
i tried to generate content Uri using FileProvider.getUriForFile() when user click specified item

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long rowId) {

     mPrivateRootDir = getFilesDir();
     mDocumentDir = new File(mPrivateRootDir,"Download");
     mDocumentFile = mDocumentDir.listFiles(); //get file in directory file[]
     mDocumentFileNames = mDocumentDir.list() //get file name String[]
     File requestedFile = new File(mDocumentDir, mDocumentFileNames[position]);
 try {
      fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.gunawan.sharedprovider.fileprovider", requestedFile);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      Log.e("File Selector", e.getMessage());
      }
    }
```

my FileProvider in Manifest

```
<provider
   android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="com.example.gunawan.sharedprovider.fileprovider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
     android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
     android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
</provider>
```

filepaths XML

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <file-path path="Download/" name="download" />
</paths>
```

its always show like this when i clicked the one of file

```
01-12 21:47:52.504 24955-24955/com.example.gunawan.sharedprovider E/File Selector: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.gunawan.sharedprovider/files/Download/0file.txt
01-12 21:47:53.824 24955-24955/com.example.gunawan.sharedprovider E/File Selector: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.gunawan.sharedprovider/files/Download/3file.txt
```

is it something wrong with the autorities?

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash from `Download/` in the `<file-path>` element.

Comment: i already try it, and still throw an error, i've no idea about this :(

Comment: it works when i recreate the project with package : com.example.sharedProvider and authorities : com.example.fileprovider i have no idea the problem